# Adding images to a PDF R markdown

Tags: r, markdown

Very new to R. I need to make a PDF document using `R markdown` for a lab report.
How do I add images to a markdown?

Answer (score 0):

You can include this in your `.Rmd` file:

```
![Add some text here](path_to_your_image)
```

I would also recommend you to take a look at this [book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/) (written by the authors of `R Markdown`) if you want to learn more.